# C++ Using an enum to error-handling

Tags: c++, dynamic, error-handling, enums

I wanted to use an Enum as an error handling, but I don't know if that's posible.

For example, if I have this enum:

```
enum ErrorNum : char{
    ID_ERROR
};
```

I want to check this ID_ERROR and, depending on that error, show a description or another. So, I don't really know how many errors would be in the app.

I'll show an example. If the algorithm can not place a bed in a room, it has to return an error with ID_ERROR 100 and X description.

But I don't know how many errors will be at the app, so I don't know if this enum should be dynamic.

I would post some code but I don't really know how to handle it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Probably. You would have to write some code around your idea. Seriously: what is your *real* question?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's a popular mechanism for error handling in C. In C++, consider using exceptions.

Comment: I just have edited the question, may be now you can understand it :)

Comment: `std::map<ErrorNum, std::string> errors;` Sample usage: `std::cerr << errors[errorcode] << '\n';` It's up to you to fill the `map` with the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, just make it be the return type of your function

```
enum ErrorNum : char{
    NO_ERROR,
    ERROR_DOING_FOO
};

ErrorNum foo()
{
    if (some_condition)
        return NO_ERROR;
    else
        return ERROR_DOING_FOO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an `enum` for error handling, you should have an `enum` value per *error type*:

```
enum class outcome
{
    success,
    error_explosion,
    error_caught_fire
};

outcome do_something() { /* return appropriate outcome */ }

int main()
{
    switch(do_something())
    {
        case outcome::success: 
            std::cout << "Success!\n";
            break;
        case outcome::error_explosion: 
            std::cout << "ERROR: the computer exploded\n";
            break;
        case outcome::error_caught_fire: 
            std::cout << "ERROR: the computer caught fire\n";
            break;
    }
}
```